# Solr Suggestion: how many doc. should contain a certain word

Tags: solr

If I have 40000 docs indexed and my threshold value is .005. how many documents should contain a certain keyword before it shows up in search suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Answer to you question is 5 by default, but you can change it if you need.

Still, you have 2 different thresholds:
mlt.mintf, Minimum Term Frequency - the frequency below which terms will be ignored in the source doc, DEFAULT_MIN_TERM_FREQ = 2
mlt.mindf, Minimum Document Frequency - the frequency at which words will be ignored which do not occur in at least this many docs, DEFAULT_MIN_DOC_FREQ = 5

I suggest to have a look at http://wiki.apache.org/solr/MoreLikeThis for all the details.

If you want to understand how "More like this" is working, I'd also suggest to read this excellent article http://cephas.net/blog/2008/03/30/how-morelikethis-works-in-lucene/

Answer (score 0):

I would say terms should appear (atleast) in 200 documents (out of 40000) to make it to the suggestion list.

200/40000=0.005

200 -> Number of documents where a particular term was present.
40000 -> Total number of documents.